# php sqlsrv connection by multiple servers to one specific database

Tags: php, database, sqlsrv

So I have 3 servers(192.168.0.21 , 192.168.0.22 and 192.168.0.23) and I would like them to connect to a database called Pensions they are all using sql server (UID and PWD)authentication. Is it possible to achieve this using php and sqlsrv_connect()? This the connect.php:

```
                <?php
            #first start session
                session_start();
            // session time out after no activity for 4 minutes
              if ($_SESSION['TimeOut'] + (5 * 60) < time()) {
                 // session timed out
                 header("Location: ./sessdestroy.php");
                 exit;
              } else {
              // store new request time.
                 $_SESSION["TimeOut"] = time();
              }

            function getConnection(){ 
                $db = 0;
                if(!$_SESSION['Database']){
                    $db = 0;
                }else{   
                 $db = $_SESSION['Database'];
                } 
            $databaseName  = 'Pension';
            if ($db == 0) 
            { // Country A
                $serverName ='192.168.0.21';
                $UID ='sa';
                $PWD ='pass!';
                $databaseName = 'Pension';
            }
            else if($db ==1)
            { // Country B
                $serverName ='192.168.0.22';
                $UID ='sa';
                $PWD ='pass!';
                $databaseName = 'Pension';

            }
            else
            { //Country C
                $serverName ='192.168.0.23';
                $UID ='sa';
                $PWD ='pass!';
                $databaseName = 'Pension';

            }
            //connection string
            //echo "test here...";

            //echo " S: ".$serverName." u: ".$UID." P: ".$PWD;
                $serverName = "serverName";
                $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"$databaseName", "UID"=>"$UID", "PWD"=>"$PWD");
                $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);

                //exit();
            //phpinfo();
                if (!$conn)
                {
                    exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn); 
                    //try local server 
                    if ($db == 1) {
                      $serverName ='192.168.0.20';
                      $UID ='fund_user';
                      $PWD ='fund_user';
                      $databaseName = 'Pension';
                      $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);
                      if (!$conn) return 0;
                      $stmt = sqlsrv_query($databaseName,$conn);
                      return $conn;
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                  $stmt = sqlsrv_query($databaseName,$conn);
                  return $conn;
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Then this is the process.php (when a connection is established it leads the user to a homepage depending on the user role )

```
                <?php
            //give no error
            ini_set("display warning",0);
            #include connection
            include('Connections/fundmaster.php');
            if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
                { 
                    session_start(); 
                } 
            //temp store for the database session before destory

            $db = 0;
            $db = $_SESSION["Database"];
            if ($db==""){
             $db = 0;
            }
             if (!isset($_SESSION["Database"]))
               {
                $_SESSION["Database"] = 0;
               }
             $_SESSION["Database"] = $db;

            if($_POST['subLogin'])
                {
                $nationalID = $_POST['sname'];
                $PWD = $_POST['Memberno'];

                $conn = getConnection();
                $sql = "select * from netlogin where NationalID = '";
                $sql .= $nationalID ."' and vcPassword= '" .$PWD."'";
                $sql = stripslashes($sql);
                $stmt = sqlsrv_query($sql, $conn);
                if($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
                    $SchemeNo = $row[0];
                    $MemberNo = $row[1];
                    $userRole = $row[6];
                    session_start();
                    if (!isset($_SESSION["SchemeNo"]))
                    {
                            $_SESSION["SchemeNo"] = $SchemeNo;
                    }
                    if (!isset($_SESSION["MemberNo"]))
                    {
                        $_SESSION["MemberNo"] = $MemberNo;
                    }
                    if (!isset($_SESSION["userRole"]))
                    {
                        $_SESSION["userRole"] = $userRole;
                    }
                    $_SESSION["SchemeNo"] = $SchemeNo;
                    $_SESSION["MemberNo"] = $MemberNo;
                    $_SESSION["userRole"] = $userRole;
                    $_SESSION["Database"] = $db; 
                     if($userRole == "1"){
                    header("Location:admin/adminarea.php");
                         }else{
                        header("Location:membersarea.php");
                          }
                }else{
                 header("Location: login.php");
                }
            }else{
                header("Location: login.php");  
            }

            ?>
```

Comment: Every server allows remote connection. What have you tried so far? What are trying to achieve?

Comment: So I have a website being accessed by 3 countries.  as servers. These servers are then supposed to connect to a database called pensions. once a connection has been established at connect.php it proceed to process.php which deals with the log in. This what the code looks like:

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider adding the database connection code and the eror you have so we can help you better. You can have a look [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)  and a very useful one [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) those ones are great for newcomers imho. @D.Dimitrov if properly configured ;-)

Comment: @sciiku dont add the code in the comments, edit your question and add the relevant nifo in it. If you get an error include it also.

Comment: @bradbury9 thank you let me do that..

Comment: @sciiku In your getConnection(), when connection to first server fails, you try to make another connection. Is that what you want to achieve or getConnection() must return only one connection, based ot $_SESSION['Database']?

Comment: @Zhorov I am trying to get the connection to work in all three servers because they are in different locations but need to access the same database.

Comment: Ok. But "I'm trying to" doesn't tell us what the _problem_ is. We can see your code. It looks like it might work. But you need to tell us any error messages you're getting when you try to connect. Or any unexpected behaviour-  e.g. does it connect to the expected database? On what basis is it supposed to know which server to connect to?

Comment: Also a separate but very serious point: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database (e.g. stealing, changing or deleting information) by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-perform-parameterized-queries?view=sql-server-2017 has documentation on how to write your queries safely using PHP / sqlsrv. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: @ADyson it is not working. The error states the connection has failed

Comment: well yes but that's because you told the PHP to say "connection failed". That doesn't give us any actual information about the real problem. Try making use of [sqlsrv_errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-errors?view=sql-server-2017) in your code so you can get proper error details. Once you've got that, you've got a much better chance of diagnosing the problem and find a solution. Right now, you can only guess.